# Настройка SSL для curl соединения (php, apache, centos)

Tags: php, curl, centos, ssl

Есть 2 сервера - удаленный и наш (клиентский). Подключение к удаленному серверу через CURL (с SSL). Есть клиентский сертификат (файлы `.crt` и `.key`).

Через openSSL с указанием сертификатов коннект идет ( `openssl s_client -debug -connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -CAfile cafile.crt -cert cert_file.crt -key key_file.key` ), при попытке обращения через curl возвращается `null`.

В apache настроены параметры `SSLCertificateFile` и `SSLCertificateKeyFile` со ссылками на сертификат и ключ в ssl.conf.
Настроен виртуальный хост `<VirtualHost *:443>` в httpd.conf. Результата эти манипуляции не дали - в любом случае возвращается null.

Каким образом можно настроить ssl соединение через curl к удаленному серверу?

Параметры curl запроса
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $cert_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $key_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $CAfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, true);

Comment: 1. уточните, пожалуйста,, о чём именно речь: о программе *curl* или о библиотеке *curl* для программы *php*. 2. в начале вы упоминаете лишь о сертификате и ключе, а среди аргументов программы *openssl* используете ещё и *certifikate authority*. вы не забываете его указывать при вызове *curl* и/или функции в *php*?

Comment: Александр,
1. Библиотека Curl для php
2. Да, пропустил, исправляюсь - используется certifikate authority, он корректный, указывается как параметр CURLOPT_CAINFO в curl_setopt()
Спасибо!

Comment: приведите пример, как именно вы указываете параметры перед вызовом http-запроса. в частности, те, что [относятся к ssl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11308270/4827341). изменить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: @alexander barakin 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT,        $cert_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,         $key_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,         $CAfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO,       true);

Comment: эту информацию лучше добавить в сам текст вопроса, нажав кнопку [edit] ниже текста вопроса.